# Label Position Appears to have gone AWOL

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

[image: Label Position Missing]

Hi, Does anyone know if Label Position has been removed from Excel 2019? Just changed over to 2019 and "Label Position" appears to be missing from Format Data Label options. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In a stacked column/bar chart, you can't set the label position. It's always centered in the segment. It's been that way since stacked charts were invented.

Oh, and please don't use 3D charts. They make reading the values from the background grid impossible. In the screenshot below, see how the totals add up to 6 and 8, but the 3D bars don't come anywhere near the grid line. In the 2D chart, however, there is no doubt about the value of the total bar.

[image]

Comment: +1 for not using 3-d charts!